# Stunnel Configuration and Startup

Tags: stunnel

Please help me to install the stunnel in redhat linux.
please share the steps
I installed the stunnel using yum install stunnel.But I am not able to start the service.please help me

Answer (score 0):

I used this guideline for the installation and configuration of stunnel:

http://help.cloud66.com/how-to/ssl-termination-on-load-balancers.html

To start the service: stunnel /etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf

In creating the pem file, you may follow the steps from this reference: http://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/pem-ssl-creation.htm